# Error when creating a new Vaadin project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, vaadin, vaadin7

When creating a new Vaadin 7 project in eclipse I'm getting this error:

```
Failed while installing Dynamic Web Module 3.1
```

(see screenshot). Anyone knows why? The sources are not begin populated.
I'm using Vaadin 7.3.6, Tomcat 8, Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1).
Thanks for your help!

[image: new Vaadin project Error]

This is the error in the log

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jst.j2ee 4 0 2014-12-15 20:41:55.090 !MESSAGE No
>   IModelProvider exists for project P/test of version: Dynamic Web
>   Module 3.1 !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException: No IModelProvider
>   exists for project P/test of version: Dynamic Web Module 3.1

Comment: Unrelated, but in the future please use .png images, not .jpg.

Comment: You may be able to find a full stack trace in your Eclipse's workspace/.metadata directory, in a file called `.log`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by installing theses:

- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
- Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
- JST Server Adapters
- JST Server Adapters Extensions